# Getting 404 using ajax in nopCommerce plugin

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce 3.40

I am getting error on ajax call in nopcommerce plugin.

view page code look like:

```
 $(function () {

        var submitButton = $("#buttonid");
        //  Attach event handler to submit button

        submitButton.click(function () {

            SubmitInfo();
        });
    });



    function SubmitInfo() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });
    }
```

controller code look like

```
public JsonResult ActionName() 
        {
          //some code here
        }
```

my current URL look like:

```
localhost:15536/Admin/Plugins/GroupName/SystemName/Configure
```

on Ajax URL in firebug Look Like:

```
localhost:15536/Admin/ControllerName/ActionName
```

I have also try with this URL but not get debug point in action:

```
localhost:15536/Admin/Plugins/GroupName/SystemName/ActionName
```

please give me some idea.

Regards,
Jatin

Comment: instead of this @Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") give direct url.... with /Admin/Controller/Action.... or use route name

Comment: @Vap thanks for your response, i am not sure what happen here but can you give me idea how to make route name in ajax?

Comment: you need to make route in your plugin route map file and give here that route name instead of url. you can find that route name how to use in nop commerce any of file.

Comment: is your issue was solve?

Comment: yes, i got the solution without making a route.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution,

when current page is opened by route then just replace

```
url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
```

to

```
url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
```

it's work for me.

Comment: i give you this option too see in my comment i write  give direct url

Comment: yes but you wrote /admin/controller/action i had try but not work for me because in my url /admin was already here.

Comment: i write that because of you write my current URL look like:

localhost:15536/Admin/Plugins/GroupName/SystemName/Configure

on Ajax URL in firebug Look Like:

localhost:15536/Admin/ControllerName/ActionName   that's why i write that, i thing that your url contains admin so you write any what work done that's good